# How get a token in spring boot 2 oauth2?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm new in spring security oauth2. I want to run this [authorization server sample code](https://github.com/talk2amareswaran/spring-boot2-oauth2-auth-server-jwt-mysql). I run it successfuly, for get token, I set postman as follow and then send request:

[image: Basic Auth]
[image: grant types]

In this case, I entered client id with its password, but I want to login without them. For example my users send username, password and client id and then get token. But every request I send, The server return 401 response. In [Spring boot 2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) oauth 2, **How can I do it?**

Comment: please post your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter

Comment: [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://github.com/talk2amareswaran/spring-boot2-oauth2-auth-server-jwt-mysql/blob/master/src/main/java/com/talk2amareswaran/projects/springboot2authserver/config/WebSecurityConfiguration.java) and [AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter](https://github.com/talk2amareswaran/spring-boot2-oauth2-auth-server-jwt-mysql/blob/master/src/main/java/com/talk2amareswaran/projects/springboot2authserver/config/OAuth2Configuration.java).

Comment: post your 401 response  Postman screenshot here

Comment: {
 "timestamp": "2018 ...",
 "status": 401,
 "error": "Unauthorized",
 "message": "Unauthorized",
 "path": "/oauth/token"
}

Comment: What do you mean with `but i want to login without theme`?

Comment: Without client id and client secret.

Comment: How are you planning to validate client without client credentials ? How is your client set up ?

Comment: I want to users send own username and password with ajax to authorization server and get token.

Answer (score 14):

1) To **get access token** you have to use such a request:

```sh
curl --user client:secret \
  -X POST http://localhost:8080/oauth/token \
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -d "grant_type=password&username=username&password=password&scope=*" \
```

with **Basic Auth** and your application credentials (you can avoid the secret if you wish). The name of the user and its password you have to pass in the body of the request as well as 'password' value in the `grant_type` field.

In response you get your access and refresh tokens, for example:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2VtYWlsIjoidXNlckBtYWlsLmNvbSIsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6InVzZXIiLCJzY29wZSI6WyIqIl0sImV4cCI6MTU0Nzc2NDIzOCwiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsiQURNSU4iXSwianRpIjoiYzk1YzkzYTAtMThmOC00OGZjLWEzZGUtNWVmY2Y1YWIxMGE5IiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiY2xpZW50In0.RWSGMC0w8tNafT28i2GLTnPnIiXfAlCdydEsNNZK-Lw",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2VtYWlsIjoidXNlckBtYWlsLmNvbSIsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6InVzZXIiLCJzY29wZSI6WyIqIl0sImF0aSI6ImM5NWM5M2EwLTE4ZjgtNDhmYy1hM2RlLTVlZmNmNWFiMTBhOSIsImV4cCI6MTU0Nzc2NzcxOCwiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsiQURNSU4iXSwianRpIjoiZDRhNGU2ZjUtNDY2Mi00NGZkLWI0ZDgtZWE5OWRkMDJkYWI2IiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiY2xpZW50In0.m7XvxwuPiTnPaQXAptLfi3CxN3imfQCVKyjmMCIPAVM",
    "expires_in": 119,
    "scope": "*"
    "jti": "c95c93a0-18f8-48fc-a3de-5efcf5ab10a9"
}
```

2) Then you can use that access token to **get access to resources** of your server application. In this case you need **Bearer Token** auth type and your access token:

```sh
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/demo \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2VtYWlsIjoidXNlckBtYWlsLmNvbSIsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6InVzZXIiLCJzY29wZSI6WyIqIl0sImV4cCI6MTU0Nzc2NDIzOCwiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsiQURNSU4iXSwianRpIjoiYzk1YzkzYTAtMThmOC00OGZjLWEzZGUtNWVmY2Y1YWIxMGE5IiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiY2xpZW50In0.RWSGMC0w8tNafT28i2GLTnPnIiXfAlCdydEsNNZK-Lw'
```

3) To **refresh token** you have to use, again, Basic Auth with client credentials, but in this case, you need 'refresh_token' as `grant_type`:

```sh
curl --user client:secret \
  -X POST http://localhost:8080/oauth/token \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'grant_type=refresh_token&scope=*&refresh_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2VtYWlsIjoidXNlckBtYWlsLmNvbSIsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6InVzZXIiLCJzY29wZSI6WyIqIl0sImF0aSI6ImM5NWM5M2EwLTE4ZjgtNDhmYy1hM2RlLTVlZmNmNWFiMTBhOSIsImV4cCI6MTU0Nzc2NzcxOCwiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsiQURNSU4iXSwianRpIjoiZDRhNGU2ZjUtNDY2Mi00NGZkLWI0ZDgtZWE5OWRkMDJkYWI2IiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiY2xpZW50In0.m7XvxwuPiTnPaQXAptLfi3CxN3imfQCVKyjmMCIPAVM'
```

Every time when the access token expires you have to refresh it with 3rd request. Then you will be able to get access to the resources again.

**Additional info**

1) My answer of [how to build the simple OAuth2 app with JWT and custom claims](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54245750)

2) [Related demo application](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-jwt-oauth-demo)

3) [Related Postman collection](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/788154/RztrLSj6)

Answer (score 2):

The OAuth 2.0 specification describes a number of grants (“methods”) for a client application to acquire an access token (which represents a user’s permission for the client to access their data).

Spring OAuth2 predefined grant types:

- ClientCredentialsTokenGranter
- RefreshTokenGranter
- AuthorizationCodeTokenGranter
- ImplicitTokenGranter
- ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter(it`s password grant type which one you use in example)

If you want to change token acquiring logic you can go with custom **TokenGranter**.

**Additional:**

[OAuth 2 Develpers Guide](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html#grant-types)